# PHP "Crypt_Blowfish" Class Initiating Errors?

Tags: php, linux, pear, mcrypt, blowfish

My PHP `Crypt_Blowfish` class initiation is throwing following error:

Error:

`Strict Standards: Non-static method PEAR::raiseError() should not be called statically, assuming $this from incompatible context in /usr/share/pear/Crypt/Blowfish/MCrypt.php on line 155 Strict Standards: Non-static method PEAR::isError() should not be called statically, assuming $this from incompatible context in /usr/share/pear/Crypt/Blowfish.php on line 199 Strict Standards: Non-static method PEAR::isError() should not be called statically, assuming $this from incompatible context in /usr/share/pear/Crypt/Blowfish.php on line 142`

Simple Code:

```
<?php
include_once('/usr/share/pear/Crypt/Blowfish.php');
$cipher = new Crypt_Blowfish("_mysalt_");
?>
```

- Is it because of `include` ? But when i disabled the `include`, again it is giving:

Error:
`Fatal error: Class 'Crypt_Blowfish' not found in /var/www/html`

So what is seriously wrong please?

- Now i'm confusing, HOW TO USE `Crypt_Blowfish` Class please? (Am i initiating it properly OR is there any other standard way to use/initiate it?)
- Or, what is the requirement to use that class? (I have run this two installation on my RHEL. `yum install php-pear-Crypt-Blowfish` and `yum install perl-Crypt-Blowfish`. And Apache Restarted. Am i still missing something?)

Please help!

Answer (score 0):

Strict standards warnings are *no* errors. You can remove them from your error_reporting setting easily:

```
error_reporting(error_reporting() & ~E_STRICT);
```

Comment: No error? If so i wonder why the code is not working then?